# ExpandableListView NullPointerException thrown when expanding group that is one higher in group position than the previously expanded group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (prev != -1 && prev != groupPosition) {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(prev);
                ImageView prevTriangle = (ImageView) expandableListView.getChildAt(prev).findViewById(R.id.triangleTop);
                prevTriangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            ImageView triangle = (ImageView) expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.triangleTop);

            //NullPointerException Thrown here when clicking on one lower:
            triangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            prev = groupPosition;
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            ImageView triangle = (ImageView) expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.triangleTop);
            triangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Here is my code. I am trying to target an ImageView in the parent's view and toggle between visible/invisible. It works great EXCEPT when expanding a parent who is one position lower than a parent who is expanded above it. At that point the ImageView reference is null, but only in this situation.

**When I say the parent is lower, I mean it's group position is one higher, or prev + 1.

Comment: Could you be more specific on where the NPE happens? Is it at `ImageView triangle`?

Comment: @mattfred yes when referencing the new ImageView triangle there is a NPE as if it does not exist. However, if the previous group was collapsed first, and then the group one higher is expanded, no NPE is thrown, and the code works as intended. It's just a situational issue that I can't wrap my head around